# HTTP Strict-Transport-Security

Tags: wordpress, http, https, http-headers

I just concluded a site vulnerability test on my new WordPress site and one of the issues I got from the results was Missing Strict-Transport-Security security header, I am not sure how I can patch up on this and improve other Security header warnings up as my site is in Wordpress, any ideas will be appreciated